# How to get or return the values from database in Json format in jsonstore Worklight 6.2?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, jsonstore, worklight-security

I have written the Json store for Getting adding replacing deleting values in Database.
i have initialized the collection.like this

```
function wlCommonInit(){
    var collections = {
       Users : {
           searchFields: { Username: 'integer', Password: 'string'}
       },
       adapter:{
           name:'SQL',
           add:'addSQL',
           remove:'deleteSQL',
           replace:'updateSQL',
           load:{
               procedure:'getSQLs',
               params:[],
           }
       }
   };
   WL.JSONStore.init(collections).then(function () {
      alert("Collection is declared");
   });}

   $("#get").bind("click",function(){
       WL.JSONStore.get("Users").load().then(function(res1){
           alert(JSON.stringify(res1));
       });
   });
```

Adapter:

```
var selectStatement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("select username, password from test");
```

function getSQLs() {

```
return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
    preparedStatement : selectStatement,
    parameters : []
});}
```

While Running this i m getting error like:

```
[wl.jsonstore] {"src":"load","err":18,"msg":"FAILED_TO_LOAD_INITIAL_DATA_FROM_ADAPTER_INVALID_LOAD_OBJ","col":"Users","usr":"jsonstore","doc":{},"res":{}}
```

Can you please let me know how do i return the value from database and how do i resolve this error.

Regards,

Sheikh Mohammed Shamnoon

Comment: Is the first field returned from your query really an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the load key which makes your load object invalid, just like the error message says (*FAILED_TO_LOAD_INITIAL_DATA_FROM_ADAPTER_**INVALID_LOAD_OBJ***).

You have:

`load:{ procedure:'getSQLs', params:[], }`

You should have:

`load:{ procedure:'getSQLs', params:[], key: yourLoadKey }`

It depends on what your getSQLs procedure calls returns, this how the key fits into the adapter response: `responseFromAdapter.invocationResult[key]`.

However, since your using v6.2 I would suggest you avoid using the `load` and `push` JSONStore APIs and follow the documentation [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_external_data.html) for working with external data.

Some sample code based on the documentation link above:

```
WL.JSONStore.init(collections)

.then(function () {

    alert('init done');

    return WL.Client.invokeProcedure({
      adapter : 'SQL',
      procedure : 'getSQLs',
      parameters : []
    });
})

.then(function (responseFromAdapter) {

    alert('responseFromAdapter:' + JSON.stringify(responseFromAdapter));

    //Look at the responseFromAdapter and call something like
    //WL.JSONStore.get('Users').add(...)
});
```

Comment: I tried with giving key :'someKey' in load previously it was not working, i dono if we mention key here how to get the response from getSQL just mentioning key is enough ? If i use the key also i was not getting response in res1...can you please suggest the write method to get response and  how to use the key in getSQL function?

Comment: Like I said before, I suggest you avoid the `load` API in favor of following the documentation for working with external data [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_external_data.html). There is no need for a load key in that case.